# Clearcase Relocation command

Tags: clearcase

I'm relocating certain files to a new VOB in ClearCase.

example:

```
VOB1/folder1/folder2/file1
```

to

```
VOB2/folder1/folder2/
```

`folder1` and `folder2` in VOB2 are newly created folders.

I cannot see the labels of `folder1` and `folder2` applied in VOB1 in VOB2.

Is there any way the labels can be copied to `folder1` and `folder2` in VOB2 from VOB1?

Answer (score 0):

Relocating files (mentioned [in your previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24650271/6309)) means the [relocation will involves only data and metadata attached to that file](https://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/cchelp/v7r0m1/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_admin.doc/topics/c_relo.htm), not to its parent folder.

> When you relocate a file element, you relocate all of the element's data and metadata.

Any label attached to the parent folder won't be relocated in that process.

> I have created a new folder and sub-folders in the destination VOB with the same name as source VOB

You actually can try to move `folder1/folder2/file1` *without* creating `folder1/folder2` first in the destination vob, and see if `folder1/folder2` are created then, with their associated label.

If that doesn't work, and your relocation is for files only, it is best to [apply the label manually (`mklabel`)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24921156/6309) for their parent folders.
See "[Need script/utility to label MOST, if not all, ClearCase elements for a given path](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24810500/6309)".